# How to use HotReload on Android Studio, using a Cellphone Device to debug

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I got some problems using Android Studio, When I connect a Device to debug, I just cant Hot Reload my codes, I have to always re-run the app, and this take a while.

> - Flutter Version: 1.7.8
> - Android SDK-Tools: 26.1.1
> - Android SDK-Plataform-Tools: 29.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! the problem was the device, which wasnot with the active buffer
I just changed to 16M on configs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where the hot reload button won't show up sometimes. The only option is to restart the android studio whenever that happened. Since that is also not a good solution I went on to using the terminal.

- Use `flutter run` command in terminal
- Then you can use `r` for hot reload or `R` for a full reload.

  I know it isn't the proper solution but until someone provides one, you can use it as it is better than re-run every time you make a small change to the app :)

Comment: Are you using a StatefulWidget ?

Comment: Yes I am. But can't we use it when there are only stateless widgets in the app?

Comment: you cannot use hot reload in stateless Widget  @Mahi

Answer (score 0):

- Flutter’s hot reload feature helps you quickly and easily experiment,
  build UIs, add features, and fix bugs.
- However, it works for **StatefulWidget** so make sure you are having a **StatefulWidget** to use hot reload option.

.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
       @override
       State<MyWidget> createState() => MyWidgetState();
 }
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
    /*
     Your code here
   */ 
   }
```

- Once you have a StatefulWidget you can simply use **Ctrl+R** to perform a hot reload.
- More details refer to [Flutter Hot Reload](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload)

---

> Because Stateless Widgets do not have a state, they will be rendered once and will not update themselves, but will only be updated when external data changes. Whereas Stateful Widgets have an internal state and can re-render if the input data changes or if Widget's state changes.

Comment: Can't we use it if we have only stateless widgets?

Comment: @Mahi I have updated my answer now you can understand difference between a stateless and Stateful widgets

Comment: I'll try that and then comeback. In my opinion the hot relode is for injecting new code to the preview that you have written so that changes reflect quickly so it should be working fine with stateful and stateless

Comment: No @Mahi stateless widgets will render only once.